# Is there a way to specify Date/Timestamp format for the incoming data within the Hive CREATE TABLE statement itself?

Tags: hive, timestamp, hiveql, create-table, hiveddl

I've have a CSV files which contain date and timestamp values in the below formats. Eg:

```
Col1|col2
01JAN2019|01JAN2019:17:34:41
```

But when I define Col1 as Date and Col2 as Timestamp in my create statement, the Hive tables simply returns `NULL` when I query.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.my_table
(Col1 date,
Col2 timestamp)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘|’
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'my_path';
```

Instead, if I define the data types as simply `string` then it works. But that's not how I want my tables to be.

I want the table to be able to read the incoming data in correct type. How can I achieve this? Is it possible to define the expected data format of the incoming data with the `CREATE` statement itself?

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

As of Hive 1.2.0 it is possible to provide additional SerDe property `"timestamp.formats"`. See this Jira for more details: [HIVE-9298](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9298)

```
ALTER TABLE timestamp_formats SET SERDEPROPERTIES ("timestamp.formats"="ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss");
```