# How to load a csv file containing time string value to timestamp in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a dataset in the below format

```
2019-10-01 00:00:00 UTC,cart,5773203,1487580005134238553,,runail,2.62,463240011,26dd6e6e-4dac-4778-8d2c-92e149dab885
2019-10-01 00:00:03 UTC,cart,5773353,1487580005134238553,,runail,2.62,463240011,26dd6e6e-4dac-4778-8d2c-92e149dab885
2019-10-01 00:00:07 UTC,cart,5881589,2151191071051219817,,lovely,13.48,429681830,49e8d843-adf3-428b-a2c3-fe8bc6a307c9
2019-10-01 00:00:07 UTC,cart,5723490,1487580005134238553,,runail,2.62,463240011,26dd6e6e-4dac-4778-8d2c-92e149dab885
```

i have created a table to load data into the table.

```
create table if not exists product_data (event_time string,event_type string,product_id string,category_id string,category_code string,brand string,price float,user_id bigint,user_session string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Is it possible to load event_time field directly as timestamp value?
Novice to Hive and any help will be much appreciated

Comment: As of Hive 1.2.0 it is possible to provide additional SerDe property "timestamp.formats" https://stackoverflow.com/a/58501775/2700344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using raw file in HDFS to load the data into hive, the recommended approach would be to first create `external table` with all the fields as `string` datatype. Once you have the external table, then load the data into a materialised table with the schema defined. This two step approach will help in ensuring you don't loose information during loading from a file.

**Step 1:** Creating an external table:

```
create external table if not exists product_data_external_table
(
 event_time string,
 event_type string,
 product_id string,
 category_id string,
 category_code string,
 brand string,
 price string,
 user_id string,
 user_session string
) row format delimited 
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
location '<your hdfs file location>'
tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

Creating a hive table with Schema defined:

```
create table if not exists product_data(
 event_time timestamp,
 event_type string,
 product_id string,
 category_id string,
 category_code string,
 brand string,
 price float,
 user_id bigint,
 user_session string
) stored as parquet;
```

**Step 2:** Inserting records into product_data from product_data_external_table:

```
insert into product_data 
select
 cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(event_time,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as timestamp) as event_time,
 event_type,
 product_id,
 category_id,
 category_code,
 brand,
 cast(price as float) as price,
 cast(user_id as bigint) as user_id,
 user_session
from 
 product_data_external_table;
```